# Vector ratios on parallelogram

Tags: geometry, vectors, ratio

There is a parallelogram ABCD.

On length CD there is point E with statement |CE|=2|ED|

On length AD there is point F with statement |AF|=1/4|AD|

Point S is intersection of length BE and CF.

**In which ratio does point S divide length BE and FC?**

[image]

The answer to this problem is:

|FS| : |SC| = 5 : 4

|ES| : |SB| = 1 : 2

I have been stuck on this problem for some time now and any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the line $l$ which is parallel to $AB$ and passes through $F$. Let $G$ denote the intersection of $l$ and line $EB$, and $H$ be the intersection with side $BC$. This introduces some useful similar triangles in the construction. Notice that:

- Triangle $BGH$ is similar to $BEC$.
- Triangle $SFG$ is similar to $SCE$.

Notice that the first ratio is straightforward since $|AF| = 1/4 |AD|$. For the ratio on the second similarity, just notice that $|DC| = 3/2 |EC|$ implies that
$$|FG| = |FH| - |GH| = 3/2 |EC| - 1/4 |EC| = 5/4 |EC|$$
and thus the ratio for the second similarity is $5/4$. From here, you can deduce the ratio $|SE|/|SB|$. Denoting $|SE|$ by $x$, we can write
$$ |SG| = 5/4 x \quad \text{and} \quad |GE| = x + 5/4 x = 9/4 x.$$
To obtain $|GB|$ in terms of $x$ we apply Tales theorem to get
$$ \frac{|GB|}{|GE|} = \frac{1/4}{3/4} = \frac{1}{3} \implies 
|GB| = 3/4 x.$$
Finally, we have
$$ \frac{|SE|}{|SB|} 
= \frac{|SE|}{|SG| + |GB|}
= \frac{x}{5/4x + 3/4x}
= \frac{1}{2}.$$
A similar reasoning can be aplied for the other ratio.

Comment: Denominator should be $5/4x+3/4x$.

Comment: Yeah, I had expressed $|GB|$ incorrectly. Just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using vectors . . .

Place the origin at $A$.

Letting $\mathbf{u}=\vec{D}$, and $\mathbf{v}=\vec{B}$, we get
\begin{align*}
\vec{C}&=\vec{D}+\vec{B}=\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}\\[4pt]
\vec{F}&={\small{\frac{1}{4}}}\vec{D}={\small{\frac{1}{4}}}\mathbf{u}\\[4pt]
\vec{E}&=\vec{D}+{\small{\frac{1}{3}}}(\vec{C}-\vec{D})=\mathbf{u}+{\small{\frac{1}{3}}}\mathbf{v}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Also, since $S$ is on the line segments $FC$ and $EB$, we get
\begin{align*}
\vec{S}&=\vec{F}+x(\vec{C}-\vec{F})=\Bigl(\frac{1+3x}{4}\Bigr)\mathbf{u}+x\mathbf{v}\\[4pt]
\vec{S}&=\vec{E}+y(\vec{B}-\vec{E})=(1-y)\mathbf{u}+\Bigl(\frac{1+2y}{3}\Bigr)\mathbf{v}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
for some $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, with $0 < x < 1$ and $0 < y < 1$.

Since the vectors $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}$ are linearly independent, we must have
\begin{align*}
\frac{1+3x}{4}&=1-y\\[4pt]
x&=\frac{1+2y}{3}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which yields $x={\large{\frac{5}{9}}}$ and $y={\large{\frac{1}{3}}}$.

It follows that

- $S$ is ${\large{\frac{5}{9}}}$ of the way from $F$ to $C$, so $|FS|{\;:\,}|SC|=5{\,:\,}4$.$\\[10pt]$

  $S$ is ${\large{\frac{1}{3}}}$ of the way from $E$ to $B$, so $|ES|{\;:\,}|SB|=1{\,:\,}2$.